# Trouble pointing or configuring Quickblox Sdk 2.4 to a new (trail) instance in android application

Tags: android, sdk, quickblox, videochat

I am using quickblox sdk 2.4 for video chat service.I used the following steps to point my android application to a new instance

//before logging into application i am setting the following instances
    QBSettings.getInstance().setServerApiDomain("apixyzquickblox.com");
    QBSettings.getInstance().setContentBucketName("...");    QBSettings.getInstance().setChatServerDomain("chatxyz.quickblox.com"); QBSettings.getInstance().setTurnServerDomain("turn.quickblox.com");
//had used appid, authkey and authsecret from an existing quickblox account
QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(Consts.APP_ID, Consts.AUTH_KEY, Consts.AUTH_SECRET);
// to set enterprise sdk they asked me to use the following code as it is
 List iceServerList = new LinkedList<>();

```
   iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", 
   null, null)); 

   iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:turn.quickblox.com", 
   "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0")); 

   iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp", 
   "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0")); 

   iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp", 
   "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0"));

   QBRTCConfig.setIceServerList(iceServerList);
```

Now i logged in to  this application on button click
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
               // **this user exists in quickblox admin panel **
                QBUser qbUser = new QBUser("abc1", "abc1234");

               QBUsers.signIn(qbUser, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                   }
               });

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                // print errors that came from server
            }
        });



});
```

when i click on next button i get  response as     **Status=422 Unprocessable Entity**
When i use the same user id in shared instance it works perfect. but as soon as i change to trial instances in enterprise  i face this problem

Please help me  fix this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first thing i want to inform you is that the documentation for quickblox that they sent me while setting the trail instance is old
And I used the same   Consts.APP_ID, Consts.AUTH_KEY, Consts.AUTH_SECRET  that was mentioned in my quickblox account.
and I configured the  code this way and it worked for me.

QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(Consts.APP_ID, Consts.AUTH_KEY, Consts.AUTH_SECRET);
QBSettings.getInstance().setServerApiDomain("apixyzquickblox.com"); QBSettings.getInstance().setContentBucketName("..."); QBSettings.getInstance().setChatServerDomain("chatxyz.quickblox.com"); QBSettings.getInstance().setTurnServerDomain("turnserver.quickblox.com");

And also there is no need to set ice servers until you have set your own custom servers